# Java to Scala syntax comparison

Tags: java, scala

Where I could find a cheat-sheet that contrast Java syntax with Scala?

A quick guide for Java programmers to learn Scala?

Answer (score 7):

How about this one? It seems to be pretty comprehensive.

http://techblog.realestate.com.au/java-to-scala-cheatsheet/

**EDIT:** I found this link simply by googling "java to scala cheat sheet"...

Comment: it's pretty recent, too

Comment: I 'm Java developer and have recently wrote a huge Scala post (to be able to use it later, as a reference) while going through the Odersky's book. Here it is: http://mbonaci.github.io/scala/

Answer (score 2):

I would advice the follwing document as a first contact with Scala for Java programmers:
[A Scala Tutorial for Java Programmers](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html)

Comment: thank you, but seems like this is not comprehensive enough

Comment: Feel free to ask questions, the Scala community is really nice to newcomers.

Comment: Glad to hear! Heard that it is an easy transition from Java to Scala , but where is the resources for that ? everything is just length explanations and not to the point.

Comment: http://samwize.com/2012/10/07/a-short-scala-tutorial-for-java-developers/ more like this ??

Comment: Seems like this community is really nice to newcomers too, thanks for holding the question!